# Accessing remote browser from local browser

Tags: web, browser, webrtc

I want to test a publicly available web application on a particular set of browser and OS (say, Firefox and Mac); the infrastructure team has provisioned for me a remote VM with these requirements.

The help I need from the community is that how can I access that remote Firefox instance from my local, say, Chrome browser instance.I want to launch the web application from remote Firefox's address bar. I *don't* want to have full access of the remote VM something which a solution like TeamViewer provides; just that remote browser.

I looked around for solutions and WebRTC cameup; however, according to my understanding I would only be able to view(read-only) whats going on in the remote browser, but I also need control on the remote browser so that I can launch web app from it, click a few buttons on the web app here and there etc.

Let me know if I have missed on any information, I would be more than happy for provide.